# Use clone helper only when button pressed

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to make it so that my draggable element is only cloned when I press the Control button and drag it. My options for the `draggable()` function are:

```
var pressedKeys = {};
window.onkeyup = function(e) { pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false; }
window.onkeydown = function(e) { pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true; }

var draggable_options = {
    snap:       '.slot',
    snapMode:   'inner',
    scroll:     false,
    start:      function(event,ui){
        if (pressedKeys[17]){
            $(ui.helper).draggable('option','helper','clone');
        }
    },
}
```

Is this even possible? I've tried `ui.element` and also `this` and neither have worked. I'm not sure if you can change options at runtime for the jquery functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var pressedKeys = {
    17: false
  };
  $(window).on({
    keyup: function(e) {
      pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
      $("#draggable").draggable("option", "helper", "original");
    },
    keydown: function(e) {
      console.log("Key Pressed: " + e.keyCode);
      pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
      $("#draggable").draggable("option", "helper", "clone");
    }
  })
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    snap: '.slot',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    scroll: false
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

An alternative solution. I would advise this solution personally.

```js
$(function() {
  var pressedKeys = {
    17: false
  };
  $(window).on({
    keyup: function(e) {
      pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
    },
    keydown: function(e) {
      console.log("Key Pressed: " + e.keyCode);
      pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
    }
  })
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    snap: '.slot',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    scroll: false,
    helper: function() {
      return (pressedKeys[17] ? $(this).clone().removeAttr("id") : $(this));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable, .ui-draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper

The `start` callback is triggered too late to generate a Clone. This is why `helper` option offers a Function to dynamically create the the helper as needed.

Here is the `_createHelper` code from the library:

```
var o = this.options,
  helperIsFunction = typeof o.helper === "function",
  helper = helperIsFunction ? $( o.helper.apply( this.element[ 0 ], [ event ] ) ) : ( o.helper === "clone" ? this.element.clone().removeAttr( "id" ) : this.element );
```

Simply perform a similar activity to replicate the code. Conditionally, it will return the original or a clone.

Comment: Super - thank you! I also used your suggested / second example. Great code.